# Excel VB pivot table

Tags: pivot-table

[image: code]I am sure this questions must have already been asked and answered, but I am novice and hope somebody will help me.
I am trying to create a macro which will loop through a pivot table Department field (This report comes from Power BI OLAP query) copy and paste the report data on to another spreadsheet and then come back to this report and look through.

I am getting error message (Run time error 1004: unable to get the pivotfields property of the pivottable class). I believe issue is with the pivotfield name Department, I have tried renaming the actual field name on the pivot to Dept still same error highlighted in bold. Any help would be very much appreciated. Many thanks in advance
Here is my code: